# vim exit after inactivity

Tags: linux, vim

I have a bad habit of leaving a vim session running in one of many, many consoles I have open.  Then at some later point, I'll want to edit that file and get the familiar complaint about it being edited somewhere else and have to tab through many consoles to find it.  Is there some clever way to have vim exit automatically if there are no changes to the open files and it's been inactive for x minutes?  I'm on linux and would be willing to use a different terminal program to get something like this working.

Answer (score 1):

The most productive solution would be to not have multiple instances of `vim` running in seperate consoles, but to familiarize yourself with the various possibilities of having multiple files open in a *single* `vim` session. I've shirked that issue for a long time myself, but once I got the hang of it, I found it to be a distinctive boost to my productivity (and terminal efficiency, too).

Check `:help windows`, `:help tabs`, and `:help split`.

**Edit:** More to the point of your original request of closing a `vim` session after inactivity: An external tool would still have to signal `vim` to properly save / close the file, so changes get saved / the `.swp` file removed. So, if there indeed *is* such a solution, it should probably come in the form of a `vim` plugin. But I know of no such plugin, and couldn't find one ad-hoc.